# Error using progressDialog in Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm developing an Activity that recollect data from an XML and show it.

I have made some tests and I guess the problem is handling the ProgressDialog, the code below works when I load the data pushing the button Refresh, but if I try to collect the data without pushing the button (if I omit the comments on loadData() ) I get an error.

So I guess the problem is in ProgressDialog but I can't detect it.

```
public class TabFeed extends ListActivity implements Callback {

    private TabFeedController controller;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public String _feedURL;

    private final Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            setData();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabfeed);

        controller = new TabFeedController(MainTabs.model);
        controller.addOutboxHandler(new Handler(this));
        /**  It gets the _feedURL through a Handler (TabFeedController)  */
        controller.handleMessage(TabFeedController.MESSAGE_SHOW_FEED, null, null);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);

        **//loadData();**
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinkedList<Element> data = controller.getDataFeed();
                if (data != null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabFeed.this);
                    builder.setMessage("New loading?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            loadData();
                        }
                    })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();                                
                        }
                    }).create().show();                         
                } else {
                    loadData();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setData(){
        this.setListAdapter(new AdapterFeedList(this, R.layout.row, 0, controller.getDataFeed()));
    } 

    private void loadData() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TabFeed.this,"", "Loading...", true);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(_feedURL);
                controller.setDataFeed(parser.parse());
                progressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch(msg.what) {
            case TabFeedController.MESSAGE_MODEL_GETFEED:
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        _feedURL = TabFeedController.FEEDURL;
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I compile it with the line loadData before the onClickListener button:

```
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460):     at ilias.XMLParser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:83)
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460):     at ilias.activities.TabFeed$3.run(TabFeed.java:115)
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460):     at ilias.XMLParser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:36)
10-25 01:46:17.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21460):     ... 2 more
```

I dont know if it's helpful. When I compile it without the line loadData, it works perfectly, but I just want to load the data firstly without push any button, that's why I load the data and start the progressDialog out of the scope of the event onClick.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually tried clicking on the "yes" button on the `AlertDialog`? Because it seems that you have actually never gotten there. I'm saying this because at first glance that errors is saying that `_feedURL` is `null` (if you haven't ommited anything that variable is never initialized), and when you say it's working it's actually not (you don't call `setData()` either after refreshing manually).

Update:

Now that we have some more information I can reensure my answer, `_feedURL` is `null`, and that happens because you are giving it a value as if it was called from a different thread because you are using `runOnUiThread`. When you make that call it is postponed until the current thread finishes, and with all the bad luck `loadData()` is being called in that moment, so the value it's not there in time. When you do it with the button it has time enough to execute both actions, that's why. A quick solution would be removing the `runOnUiThread` part (the handler is the activity itself, so you are on the UI thread), but I guess it's better to ask this question:

> Why are you even using a handler to give a value to a variable?

If you want to give it a value, just give it, remove all thet handler part and `onCreate()` put:

```
_feedURL = TabFeedController.FEEDURL;
```

Comment: Sorry, I omitted some code because I thought it was innecesary, I'll edit it. The code shows how I get _feedURL.

Comment: Oh I have detect the problem. If I write directly the URL of the feed in "XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(_feedURL);" it works. But I don't understand why it gets it correctly through the button and don't if I loadData before the onClick.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem. I'm developing this program into a MVC patter and I thought the best solution to encapsulate the activity and the controller was to send messages by handlers but I guess that sometimes we have to keep it easier if I just wanted to get a value.
Thanks

Comment: It's a bit redundant what you did, that would be fine if you need to asynchronously send data to the view from the controller or at least pass any data, but the calls were something like: the view tells the controllers that it needs the url, the controller says "yeah, get it" to the view, then the view goes to the controller again and gets it hehehe.